# FastAPI - Supporting Either Basic Auth Or JWT Auth to Access Endpoint

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, jwt, fastapi, basic-authentication

Referencing this link:
[fastapi-supporting-multiple-authentication-dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731890/fastapi-supporting-multiple-authentication-dependencies)

I think this is the closest to what I need, but somehow I can’t get either of the dependency to work because fastapi is enforcing both dependencies before it grants access to endpoint.

Snippet for custom depedency:

```
def basic_logged_user(credentials: Annotated[HTTPBasicCredentials, Depends(security)]):
    current_username_bytes = credentials.username.encode("utf8")
    correct_username_bytes = settings.SESSION_LOGIN_USER.encode("utf8")
    is_correct_username = secrets.compare_digest(
        current_username_bytes, correct_username_bytes
    )
    current_password_bytes = credentials.password.encode("utf8")
    correct_password_bytes = settings.SESSION_LOGIN_PASS.encode("utf8")
    is_correct_password = secrets.compare_digest(
        current_password_bytes, correct_password_bytes
    )

    if not (is_correct_username and is_correct_password):
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Invalid Credentials",
            headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Basic"},
        )
    return credentials.username


def jwt_logged_user(token: str = Depends(utils.OAuth2_scheme), 
                    db: Session = Depends(db_session)):
    credential_exception = HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                                         detail="Incorrect username or password",
                                         headers={"WWW-Authenticate": "Bearer"})

    token = utils.verify_token(token, credential_exception)
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.username == token.username).first()

    return user


# custom auth
def auth_user(jwt_auth: HTTPBearer = Depends(jwt_logged_user), 
                    basic_auth: HTTPBasic = Depends(basic_logged_user)):
    if not (jwt_auth or basic_auth):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, 
                            detail='Invalid Credentials')


#endpoint
@router.get("/")
async def get_users(db: Session = Depends(db_session), logged_user: str = Depends(auth_user)):
    query_users = db.query(User).all()

    return query_users
```

I expect it to grant me access to endpoint when I provide correct credential for JWT auth or Basic Auth, but it still forces me to put in credential for both. How can I achieve this effect of providing any one of the 2 auth but not both.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76160945/17865804) helpful

Comment: Thanks, @Chris for pointing out this link, it contains some helpful detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to make all of this security dependencies not to raise exceptions on user authentication error at the dependency resolving stage.

For `HTTPBasic` pass `auto_error=False`:

```
security = HTTPBasic(auto_error=False)
```

And then in `basic_logged_user` you should check that

```
def basic_logged_user(credentials: Annotated[Optional[HTTPBasicCredentials], Depends(security)]):
    if credentials is None:
        return None
    ...
    # Do not raise exception, but return None instead
```

You need to find the way how to do the same with your second authentication scheme (`utils.OAuth2_scheme`) - not to raise `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED`, but return `None` instead.

Then your `auth_user` will work as you expect. It will raise `HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED` only if both schemes return `None`.

Comment: I see, this make sense, I will try this approach and give a feedback.
Thanks @yurii

Comment: It. worked! 
This is exactly the whole idea as you said, not to raise any exceptions but return None, so the final check function can easily resolve all the dependencies and raise the exception. Nice trick .
Thanks @Yurii