FastAPI endpoint secured by X-API-Key or JWT- problem with dependency
I am trying to secure FastAPI endpoint by JWT and X-API-Key (in a header). If JWT is provided it should be user, if not FastAPi should verify X-API-Key. Reason is i want to use the same API service for different ways how client apps are authorizing.
check_validation function works fine only if X-API-Key is provided. if X-API-Key is not provided this function is not called.
This is my code
app = FastAPI( title="API", version="1.0", description="API",)

origins = [
      "http://localhost:8080"
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],)

get_bearer_token = HTTPBearer(auto_error=False)
api_key_header = APIKeyHeader(name="X-API-Key") 

def check_authorization(auth: t.Optional[HTTPAuthorizationCredentials] = Security(get_bearer_token), api_key_header: t.Optional[str] = Security(api_key_header)):

    if auth:
        print("verifing bearer token as authorization method ")
        try:
            decoded_data = jwt.decode(jwt=auth.credentials,
                                key=api_config.jwt_secret,
                                algorithms=["HS256"],
                                options={"verify_aud": False, "verify_signature": True}
                                )
        except BaseException as auth_error:
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
                detail="Wrong JWT token "+str(auth_error)
            )

    else:
        print ("verifing api key as authorization method ")
        raise HTTPException(
            status_code=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED,
            detail="Missing or invalid API key"
    )

@app.get("/test")
async def test (user: dict = Depends(check_authorization)):
    return "Test OK"



So what is your error? What happens? What request are you sending?

If X-API-Key is not provided but still JWT is there I get 430 Forbidden.
If X-API-Key is provided together with JWT - JWT is verified (check_authorization function is executed)
if X-API-Key is provided without JWT - X-API-Key is verified (check_authorization function is executed)
so the problem is if the client wants to authorize via JWT (not providing X-API-Key) check-authorization method is not called

I have solved using this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64731890/fastapi-supporting-multiple-authentication-dependencies
